# uwsgi ImportError: No module named myproject.settings

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm receiving the following errors while trying to launch my site using django, uwsgi and nginx

> ImportError: No module named MIVT.settings

My folder/file structure are as follows

-webapp

--myproject

---wsgi.py

--- **init.py**

---settings.py

Inside my uwsgi.ini file for the project I have the following.

```
# mivt_uwsgi.ini

[uwsgi]
plugin=python
pidfile = /home/mysuer/webapp/webapp-pid.pid
chdir = /home/mysuer/webapp/myproject
wsgi-file = /home/mysuer/webapp/myproject/wsgi.py
home = /home/mysuer/webapp/myproject/myprojectvirtual
master = true
processes = 10
socket = /home/mysuer/webapp/myproject/proj.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = false
```

I've based this project off of another one that works just fine. Any clues to why I'm getting the no myproject.settings found would really help out. It finds the wsgi.py file just fine.

Comment: Is your app `webapps` or `webapp`?

Comment: webapps is misspelled. Sorry. I'll fix that right now.